# Change the order of a sort criteria in views to a custom hierarchy

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type called `Technique` that contains a title field, a description field, and a node reference called "belt level" referencing a content type called `Curriculum level`. The content in `Curriculum level` are as follows:

- Yellow belt
- Orange belt
- Blue belt
- Brown belt
- Red belt
- Black belt

I have created an Integer field in the `Curriculum level` content type called `level int`. I have set "yellow" to 1, "orange" to 2, "blue" to 3, "brown" to 4, "red" to 5, and "black" to 6. Now I have a view of `techniques`, in which I want the sort criteria to display results based on the `level int` field value of the content that the node reference field (called "belt level") in the technique was referencing. The problem I am running into is that I have no way of connecting the two. If I use the `belt level` field to try to set the sort criteria, I can only sort it alphabetically based on the title. How can I sort it based on the `level int` field instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a relationship `Content: belt level` (or whatever your node reference field is called) to the view.

Then add a new sort, choose `Content: level int` (or whatever the integer field is called) and under 'relationship' choose the one you just added.

That should do it.

Comment: I used the relationship `Content: level int` and it worked, but I noticed that right underneath it was a relationship called `Content: level int  - reverse`. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: The reverse one is for retrieving content which references that node, rather than the content which that node references. So in this case, `Content: level int` would return the belt level's integer value, whereas `Content: level int - reverse` would return all the `Technique`s that reference the belt level.
In this case it's useless but it could be used, for example, on a page listing all the belt colors in order to display a list of techniques belonging to each belt. (Although that's a bad example as it could be done better using grouping).